# Something weird about Datagridview formatting/paintng event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
 If e.RowIndex < 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In wgrid.Rows
        Dim n1 As Integer = rw.Cells(5).Value + rw.Cells(6).Value 
        Dim n2 As Integer = rw.Cells(3).Value + rw.Cells(4).Value
        Dim quo As Double = n1 / n2
        If quo >= 0.5 And quo < 0.9 Then
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        ElseIf quo >= 0.9 And quo <= 1 Then
            rw.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            MsgBox("red")
        End If
    Next
```

The code above — sans the MsgBox — was in the Datagridview's CellPainting event and its fine at first glance. Then I added the MsgBox, and I was surprised that the "red" dialog box popped out infinitely (or so it seemed to me), a new one appearing after I closed the last, even though I'm sure there's only one record that meets the if condition. I tried transferring the code to the RowPostPaint event, and even deleting all but one record from the dataset, to the same results.

Can someone explain this to me and how can I fix it?

Comment: because CellPainting happens **a lot**. when you close the Dialog the cell has to be painted which causes the Dialog to show, which cause the cell to paint, which... GoTo 10

Comment: Never debug painting events with a MessageBox.

Comment: get rid of the dialog and problem solved.  to debug use `Debug.Print` or `console.WriteLine` and look in the Debug/Output window for messages.